# Can read data without content-type?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, content-type

If send data without content-type header, can i read data?

I just tried to read in nodejs with bodyparser, but i could not read.

NODEJS always receive empty request body.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `body-parser` you need to specify the content type, otherwise express (which I think it is what you are using) won't be able to read the body.

You can always access the raw body:

```
app.use (function(req, res, next) {
    var data='';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
       data += chunk;
   });

   req.on('end', function() {
       req.body = data;
       next();
   });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // you have set the body before:
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: it would be fantastic if you mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Content type as `application/json` for body parser to parse data into json.